# Old new contributor?

Tags: discussion

Out of curiosity, nothing urgent. I have spotted, over last couple of months, few poor quality questions from same user, having an alias quite easy to remember. I seem to remember having answered few of them, but now I can't find anything but the most recent question from today. What is more confusing, the profile of the user indicates he has been member for 1 year and 1 month, while he is being shown with **New contributor** tag. Could this be a new user signing up with the same alias, or? Could this be caused by the only visible question being from today, as I also suspect him of deleting his old questions.

Comment: I _think_ the `New contributor` tag is based on reputation, not account age. If this user is in fact an existing user all of whose contributions have been deleted and who hasn't otherwise built > 10 rep, they would get the `New contributor` tag.

Comment: The User in question has deleted some of their questions, but only 5 and the earliest is from September of last year.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, @AdrianLarson - I assume it is not against community guidelines to remove your old questions, even though they do have upvoted answers?

Comment: It's not explicitly against guidelines. However, the automated filtering system treats such behavior as a *major* red flag, and it usually leads to question bans.